# Regular Expression for nickname

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am really newbie at RegExp's and I can't build it right now, so I've reffered to Stack Overflow.

Rules:

1. Can contains from 6 up to 15 symbols
2. Symbols can be latin letters, numbers, underline charachter.
3. Nickname **must** begin from letter

I don't know how to make this regular expression. I need to use it in Javascript and PHP, so I need solution for each platforms.

Comment: You _need_ code? Well, start coding. This is not a "here's the requirement thx bye" site http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I can't do it because I can't understand Regexp syntax anyway. I will learn it, but I need solution right now.

Comment: You'll be a newbie at RegExps forever if you don't try first before asking someone else to do all of the work for you.

Comment: @DamienPirsy That was incorrect statement - I need solution, I will write code. I need explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something to get you started, but you'll need to tweak it and adapt it to what you need:

```
[a-zA-Z]\w{5,14}
^       ^
|       match an alphanumeric or underscore character 5 to 14 times
|
match a single alphabetic character
```

Comment: You could even make it shorter by using the i modificator `/^[a-z]\w{5,14}$/i`

Comment: True, but I wanted it to be as straightforward as possible

Comment: Thanks. I will learn RegExp right tomorrow.

Comment: Shouldn't the second z be capital?

Comment: @flec - You are absolutely right, thanks!

Comment: @tucnak you could accept his answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{5,14}$/
```

It should work both on PHP and in JS.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand. Now it looks simplier. I will study regexp. I will study regexp. I will study regexp. I will study regexp. I will study regexp.